# App not working when compiled by CodeDom but it works through Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to use CodeDom compiler in my .NET application to compile other .NET application. It is compiling just fine BUT the application (which was compiled with CodeDom) seems not to work properly (at least with `System.Net` things).

The weird thing is when I launch the app through Visual Studio (or I compile it with Visual Studio), it works perfectly fine. But when the exact same application is compiled with CodeDom, it is not working.

Why? Any ideas?

```
try
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://discordapp.com/api/v9/users/@me");
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", token);
        request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11");

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string resp = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            if (resp.Contains("{\"id\":\"") || resp.Contains("\",\"username\":\""))
                return true;
        }
    }
}
catch 
{
}

return false;
```

This piece of code that is working with VS but not with CD

I checked the CodeDom compiler version. It seems to be fine.
Referenced assemblies seems to be fine too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CodeDom` is long obsolete, it only supports up to C# 5, and certainly no `async`. You want to use Roslyn instead (for example, starting with `MSBuildWorkspace`, or building your own workspace by hand).